# Android Ratingbar has no response

Tags: java, android, xml, ratingbar

I am making a Ratingbar to allow user to rate for something.
Thus,I use this java code

```
    setContentView(R.layout.restaurant_detail);
    value=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView23) ;
    rb=(RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    rb.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new 
    RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,float rating,boolean fromUser){
        value.setText("Rated:"+rating)}
    });
```

and this xml code

```
<RatingBar
      android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
      style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:isIndicator="true"
      android:numStars="5"
      android:rating="4.5"
      android:stepSize="0.5" />

<TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView23"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="TextView" />
```

but the Ratingbar does not change when I press on it. I have done many searching in vain,please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: do you get any errors ?

Comment: Sir,the compiler does not show any error.

Comment: did your app crashed ?

Comment: @Michael you can look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try modify to this

```
 rb.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
         boolean fromUser) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Selected Ratings  : " + String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="4.5"
    android:stepSize="0.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView23"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Just setting `android:isIndicator="false"` in the `RatingBar`

Then use in the Activity .

```
rb.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar,float rating,boolean fromUser){
        value.setText("Rated:"+rating)}
});
```